How to set Authorization header for every request in Playwright
I have a login endpoint /api/v1.2/Login
upon sending a post request with the payload
{
  "organisation": "organisation123",
  "username": "username123",
  "password": "password123"
}

I get a response like
{
    "access_token": "12345",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 14400,
    "refresh_token": ""
}

Now every authorized request to the API requires the Authorization header to be set with the value Bearer 12345
I want to, in Playwright, be able to login and store the access_token and then set the Authorization header for every subsequent request.

test('foo', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.request.post('/testendpoint'); // this post request should now have Authorization header set
});



How can I achieve this?
